# Conditionally choosing biblatex backend

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

To simplify collaboration with others I would want to have *something like the following pseudo-code* in my preamble.

```
  
if passing bibtex:
       then use backend bibtex
else
      use biber backend
```

Is there a way to achieve this using a `if-then-fi` statement?

Thank you for your time in advance.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't really understand. Why not just use 2 lines - one for each backend - and comment out the inactive one? Why add a conditional when saying e.g. `\bibtexfalse` in the preamble is no less work than commenting out the `backend=bibtex` line? That is, it is easy to add a conditional and then test that conditional and set the backend, but that seems a lot more complicated!

Comment: `\newif\ifbibtexbackend \bibtexbackendfalse \ifbibtexbackend \usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex} \else \usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex} \fi` ??? But why ???

Comment: There are two reasons: Some collaborators aren't comfortable with directions `comment line so and so`. Secondly I thought it would be more elegant than having to comment out (it could be my ignorance)....

Comment: Just because a user is used to hit the BibTeX button in the editor, LaTeX cannot know about it and cannot decide which backend to use for package `biblatex`. Instead of trying to find a nice way for checking, you should find a solution that suits the most.

Comment: This is a little off-topic but with biblatex 3.4 we are officially beginning the deprecation process for the bibtex backend because maintaining two backends is a pain and there are now a large amount of biblatex features which bibtex as the biblatec backend can't handle.

Comment: Thanks just wanted to put out there:  The problem is arxiv still doesn't have biber support. So that  creates a lot of problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a conditional and test it.

```
\newif\ifbibtexbackend 
\bibtexbackendfalse 
\ifbibtexbackend 
  \usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex} 
\else 
  \usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex} 
\fi
```

As I say, I don't see the point as I think

```
% uncomment this line and comment the next to use the BibTeX backend
%\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex} 
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
```

is a lot more straightforward for people to understand.

Comment: **A dumb question:** How does latex *"understand"* that *bibtexbackend* is **the backend** parameter to biblatex? As far as I understand it is not defined in biblatex package. Thank you for your time!

Comment: What do you mean? I think the answer is: it doesn't. You understand that but LaTeX doesn't. The conditional could be called anything. `\newif\ifrabbitwarren ... \ifrabbitwarren \usepackage[backend=bibtex]...`. It only triggers the use of that backend because that's what you tell it to do if the conditional is true. There's no other connection. Or, to put it another way, LaTeX's understanding just is the code above. That is what constitutes the connection. Nothing more.